# API works fine but parameters are not accepted c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I have my route prefix here:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/Adresses")]
public class AdressesController : ApiController
{
```

My function here:

```
[Route("{codeEtudiant}")]
// GET: api/Adresses/1
public IEnumerable<Object> getAdresseEtu(Int32 code)
{
```

Where I call my api:

```
using (var client2 = new HttpClient())
{
    string getasync = "http://localhost:11144/api/Adresses/" + etu.Code;
    var response2 = await client.GetAsync(getasync);
    var json2 = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    int cpt2 = -1;
    foreach (object tmp2 in JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Object>>(json2))
    {
```

My string getasync returns: `http://localhost:11144/api/Adresses/1`

With these methods I can call any function in my api that does not have parameters but as soon I have one it doesn't respond and give me a response:

> 404 reason(not found)

Answer (score 4):

The parameter names have to match. Currently you have the route parameter named `codeEtudiant` but the parameter of the method named `code`. Give them both the same name.

```
[Route("{codeEtudiant}")]
public IEnumerable<Object> getAdresseEtu(Int32 codeEtudiant)
```

See also [Attribute Routing in ASP.NET Web API 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2).

Answer (score 0):

The error is because the Route Attribute must have the same name of the parameter, use

```
[Route("{code}")]
```